# Пересылка строки из письма в зависимости от ее содержимого

Tags: post, java

Задача: c помощью вот такого кода я получаю содержимое тела письма

```
FlagTerm ft = new FlagTerm(new Flags(Flags.Flag.SEEN), false);
Message[] messages = folder.search(ft);
for (int i = 0, n = messages.length; i < n; i++) {
    System.out.println(i + ": " + messages[i].getFrom()[0] + "\t" +       messages[i].getContent());
}
```

В первой строке письма приходят значения

> `earthquake, 5 hours 27 minutes ago, Altay-Sayan region, magnitude 2.8, depth 10 kilometers`

Вопрос: как при любых значениях magnitude выше 2.0 , отправить всю эту строку на другой адрес? И ещё, как реализовать запуск этого скрипта через каждые 30 секунд?

Answer (score 1):

1. Через Regex вытаскиваете значение магнитуды. Паттерн регекса будет выглядеть примерно так

   `Pattern magnitudePattern = Pattern.compile("magnitude\\s+(\\d+\\.\\d+),");`
2. Если больше 2.0 отправляете
3. Запуск через промежутки времени можно так

   `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
   executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new SenderThread(), 0, 30 , TimeUnit.SECONDS);`

Где в методе `run()` класса `SenderThread` будет запуск скрипта. Вроде всё.

Comment: Если честно, почти ничего не понял. Логику как это сделать я примерно представляю, меня интересует листинг кода хотя бы для примера...

Comment: 1.  
    

  double magnitude=0.0;
  Pattern pat=Pattern.compile("magnitude ([^,]+)");
  Matcher match=pat.matcher("earthquake, 5 hours 27 minutes ago, Altay-Sayan region, magnitude 2.8, depth 10 kilometers");
  if (match.find()) magnitude=Double.parseDouble(match.group(1));
        if (magnitude>2) sendMessage();

Comment: Ну код проверки выше написали. Теперь пишете класс
public class SenderThread extends Thread {

@Override
public void run() {
...
}

Вместо многоточия вставляете код проверки магнитуды

Comment: Теперь возникает другой вопрос, а каким образом передать полученную строку после проверки в другой класс? В другом файле у меня реализована отправка письма SendUpp().test()

Comment: Как реализован класс отправки сообщения?